# iterating over an array with polymer "importHref" as callback

Tags: jquery, polymer

i have an array that i want to iterate over and use polymer 1.0 **importHref** as a calback function. So far its working but its calling each element in the array 10x.

Here is my code

```
var widgets = Object.keys(e.detail.response); //["pl-left-drawer", "pl-logo", "pl-site-title", "pl-layout-switch", "pl-search", "pl-messages", "pl-alerts", "pl-tasks", "pl-settings", "pl-right-drawer"]
        var total = widgets.length;
            console.log(widgets);
        for (var i=0; i < total; i++) {
            Polymer.Base.importHref('/themes/components/custom_components/'+ widgets[i] + '/'+ widgets[i] +'.html', function(e) {
                // e.target.import is the import document.
                console.log(e.target.import + 'has been imported');
            }, function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.import + 'has not been imported');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the server was denying access to the import files... (all requests to my server are routed to an index file) and instead, served the index file as the import file *sic. Thus the process was caught in a loop, i.e, the index file is served as the import file and the served file imports again. (thats what happens when you set iron ajax to auto)